# How do I get JQuery code to run on my browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to JQuery and I am trying to figure out how to get my .mouseenter() and .mouseleave() methods to work. So far I have tried using IE8 and FF, but for some strange reason I can not get my elements to do anything other than remaining static. Here's the code that I have so far:

HTML:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///D:/Documents%20and%20Settings/stsc/My%20Documents/_prac/script.js"></script>
        <title>Practice</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="red"></div>
        <div id="yellow"></div>
        <div id="green"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    height:100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

#red{
    background-color: red;
}

#yellow{
    background-color: yellow;
}

#green{
    background-color: green;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            width: '+=10px'
        });
    });
    $('div').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            width: '-=10px'
        });
    });
    $('div').click(function() {
        $(this).toggle(1000);
    });
});
```

This is just a simple example to practice using JQuery. Thanks in advance for the help guys!

Comment: Press 'F12' when you're in your browser, you'll see a console being brought up, the error most likely states, `'Unable to load resource: Resource not found'` with a `500 server error`.

Comment: Well, you'll need to include jQuery (in your example you don't).

Comment: I copied and pasted the above code into [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XNAKj/)

Comment: Also, it's probably better to have a relative path to your `script.js`. And according to the [documentation for .animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) it appears that you don't need to include the 'px' at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the response! That was the problem, I didn't add the library.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///D:/Documents%20and%20Settings/stsc/My%20Documents/_prac/script.js"></script>` this part is wrong http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Comment: @JSCOTT12 - The good news is that your example runs fine when jQuery is included!

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to be including jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Also, is the D:\ drive a hard drive or a CD/DVD drive?  That could be an issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should reference the jquery library inside your HTML:

```
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///D:/Documents%20and%20Settings/stsc/My%20Documents/_prac/script.js"></script>
    <title>Practice</title>
</head>
```